# How to do «execute immediatly» by default for each new phrase in PhraseExpress?

Tags: phraseexpress

I want to insert my snippets without additional keystrokes. For each snippet I have to choose *Execute immediatly*.

[image: Execute immediatly]

Can I make *Execute immediatly* was the default, and I would not have to every time to change this setting manually?

I searched in *Tools*, *Expert mode*, Google, but I have not found the answer to my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is possible to change the mode of input of snippets only in separate folders, but not at the global level. If the snippet is not in the folder, set the value will have to manually. By default value is `Execute after default delimiter`.

Left-click on folder name and changing `Execute after default delimiter` to `Execute immediately`.

[image: Execute immediatly]

All snippets in the folder will have a value `Execute immediately` by default.

Comment: How the "Execute after default delimiter" works at all? What is the default deliminer? I set immediatelly just because then it works.